# Could we (eventually?) have tooltips for emoji?

Tags: feature-request, accessibility

Twitter has this lovely feature where emoji have tooltips:

[image]

This has some nice aspects. That lets me know that isn't a curiously shaped rocket, a really drunk snow-witch, or a rectangle. It also means when an emoji is hard to see or isn't available on the user's system, there's a back up way to see it.

I don't know if they work as alt text (but that would be lovely too)

This seems like a great accessibility feature that I'm surprised I haven't seen elsewhere.

It would be good to see something come out of Twitter for SE as well.

It's not really something I expect to be on the roadmap but could we consider some version of this feature in future?

Comment: Source code to implement your request is available here: https://twemoji.twitter.com/  https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

Comment: But tool tips are **not** accessible. (Discord has a similar feature but it’s activated on click/tap so touchscreens can take advantage—not sure about keyboard users.)

Comment: If you can't quite see, or understand emoji, its helpful, and can tie in with alt text.

Answer (score 15):

I.... highly doubt we would ever do something like this.

What Twitter actually does is convert all emoji into an image. If you can load the images, all emoji look the same for all users. If you cannot load the image, it puts the actual Unicode character into the alt text of the image so that gets displayed instead. This inherently allows you to set a title as well, since it's an image and not just plain-text (and from my experience, they don't actually place that title on every occurrence and I have no idea why).

Even without using this image approach, adding a title there would still require us to:

1. Maintain a database of all Unicode characters with equivalent pretty names to display for them, or at least jack into an API somewhere (if one exists) to do so.
2. Replace every Unicode character that is not a standard word character with something akin to `<span title="{pretty_title}">{character}</span>` so that we can actually display the title for them.

I would say that this is a prohibitively expensive task for the minimal gain it would achieve. Nice for someplace like Twitter where emoji are used constantly, but a bit overkill for our network.

Comment: I agree that it'd be overkill for this network, but FWIW, it's easy enough to get the name of an emoji (or any other Unicode char). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264457/4014959) is a short demo I wrote a few years ago in Python, using a standard library module; I assume similar APIs are available in other languages.

Answer (score -2):

Using emoji instead of words makes the message more fun but impairs the meaning of the post.  To add such an option would be encouraging this.

Comment: This does not work. The HTML is stripped from the post.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my post.

Comment: With Stack Exchange Markdown/HTML, you can only add `title` attributes (which are what create native tooltips) to `<img>` and `<a>` elements. Please see [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) OTOH, you could use a snippet to add more involved HTML/CSS/JavaScript.